# Javascript - Open a 3rd party web page in new tab and login

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my web application, I want to open a 3rd party web server page in a new tab. I achieved this by using below source.

```
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.target = "_blank";
            a.href = 'http://<ipAddress:port>/#/signin';
            a.click();
```

Now I want to log the user to this 3rd party web by providing username and password. Single sign on concept is not possible here as the 3rd party web got different authentication and token strategy. So outcome of this is to log a user into a 3rd party web server without letting user to enter login credentials to the application.

Appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Comment: Yep, looks like this 3rd party website did the right thing to protect itself

Comment: What you are asking is not possible

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Yes that's true @AlonEitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve what you want to do using javascript, unless the 3rd party lets you access some kind of API to log on to their system.

You cannot inject JavaScript code into a 3rd party site and that's a crucial security feature. As soon as you redirect to the 3rd party site, your JavaScript code will just be terminated by the browser no matter what you try.

So either let your users log in manually, or get the 3rd party to cooperate with you in implementing some kind of single-sign-on mechanism.

Comment: It supports active directory support for single sign-on, but active directory isn't used for authentication in the application. Therefore if needed to achieve this, it's only manual log-in in my case. Thanks for the reply.